# Vimeo api v3 get vimeo user feed

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to use this api point: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/users#GET/users/{user_id}/feed

However when I enter some user id here:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/users/a/feed

and set "Authenticate this call as ...", (I do have token with private scope) I always get this error:

```
"error": "You do not have the proper permissions.",
"link": null,
"developer_message": "The account being accessed does not have sufficient permissions to execute this operation.",
"error_code": 3200
```

I can successfully retrieve some other api endpoints like channel videos, group videos etc..

Comment: Does the same behavior occur when making the same request using a REST client like curl or Postman?

Comment: I tried on their api link above and on my side using their Vimeo api php library.